# How to do variable unpacking using Go

Tags: go

I am trying to write a program using Go which perform tuple or variable unpacking as below in python

```py
url = ('https://www.amazon.com/War-Art-Through-Creative-Battles' '/dp/1936891026/?keywords=war+of+art')
domain , *rest , isbn = url.split("/")[2:-1]
```

So I have written code as below using Go

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    var a string
    a = ("https://www.amazon.com/War-Art-Through-Creative-Battles" +
        "/dp/1936891026/?keywords=war+of+art") // dont use ' quotes
    fmt.Println(a)
    split_a := strings.Split(a, "/")
    fmt.Println(split_a)
    var rest []string
    var domain string
    var isbn string
    domain, rest, isbn = split_a[2:-1]
}
```

and getting `cannot assign 1 values to 3 variables compiler WrongAssignCount`.

I understand the error as it reflects what I am trying to achieve, I am trying to find out the methods to achieve this and finally thought of checking with others. Any suggestions much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Tag for what kind of experts can help you with your problem. Someone who knows Python and not Go is no help here (whereas someone who knows Go and not Python is still probably able to help), so the Python tag isn't appropriate.

Comment: `d = split_a[split_a.length - 3]` ... ect.

Comment: `domain, rest, isbn := split_a[2], split_a[3:len(split_a)-2], split_a[len(split_a)-2]` https://play.golang.org/p/yoU6AF3ydB0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just string manipulation, so no one right answer. Since your source is a
URL, I would say `net/url` is a good starting point:

```
package main

import (
   "net/url"
   "path"
)

func main() {
   p, e := url.Parse(
      "https://www.amazon.com/" +
      "War-Art-Through-Creative-Battles/dp/1936891026/?keywords=war+of+art",
   )
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   rest, isbn := path.Split(path.Clean(p.Path))
   println(
      p.Host == "www.amazon.com",
      rest == "/War-Art-Through-Creative-Battles/dp/",
      isbn == "1936891026",
   )
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/net/url